# Writing to internal storage in c++ from jni

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to write a file in the internal storage directory of my application with the following step :

1) Initializing my "jni library" in Acivity Class :

```
MyLib mylib = new MyLib();
```

2) Give the internal storage path by calling getFilesDir in my Activity Class:

```
mylib.setSavePath(getFilesDir());
```

3) Call a method mylib.save() from my library which is doing the following in c++:
Open the file which i want to write with :

```
fp = fopen(pathtotheinternalstorage+filename,"w");
if (!fp) {
    SetError(XML_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, filename, 0);
    return _errorID;
}
```

The file path is correct : /data/data/com.myapp/files/myfile.xml
But fopen fails, i dont know what i am doing wrong.
If i write with some java code (openFileOutput), it is working well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: paste the code . exact error message

Comment: Did you check if you have / between pathtotheinternalstorage and filename?

Comment: Yes the path is correct : /data/data/com.myapp/files/myfile.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, i was using a library that was redefinig fopen to read inside asset folder.

```
#define fopen(name, mode) android_fopen(name, mode)
```

now it s working

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful.  Based on the path, I'm assuming you're on a Linux box.  I would first check the permissions of the path.  A few suggestions below

1) Try opening a file in your home directory and see if you have the same issue.

2) Try setting the file world writable using `chmod 777` and see if that fixes the problem.  Remember setting world writable is really INSECURE and you should change it to something more restrictive once you've found the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I am currently developing on android so i cant set permission as i want